# Security of a "contact us" form

Tags: php, security, form, email

I have a form, which uses AJAX to send POST data to the following controller method:

```
public function action_sendmail() {
        $jsonHelper=Loader::helper('json');
        $answer = (int) $_POST['security'];
        if($answer <= 0)
            $answer = 1;

        if($answer == 4){

            $name = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
            $message = filter_var($_POST['message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

            $name = strip_tags($name);
            $email = strip_tags($email);
            $message = strip_tags($message);

            $name = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d"), '', stripslashes($name));
            $email = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d"), '', stripslashes($email));
            $message = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d"), '', stripslashes($message));

            if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                echo $jsonHelper->encode(t("Wrong email address."));
                die;
            }
            if(preg_match("/^[+]?[0-9]*$/", $_POST['phone'])) {
                $phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);
            }
            else {
                echo $jsonHelper->encode(t("Wrong phone number format."));
                die;
            }

            $message = t('Phone number').": ".$phone."\n\n".$message;

            $mail = Loader::helper('mail');
            $mail->setBody($message);
            $mail->from($email, $name);
            $mail->to("test@example.com");
            $mail->to($email);
            $mail->setSubject(t('Example subject'));

            $sent = true;

            $mail->sendMail();

            if($sent) {
                echo $jsonHelper->encode("sent");
                die;
            }
            else {
                echo $jsonHelper->encode(t("Could not send mail. Please try again."));
                die;
            }

        }
        else{
            echo $jsonHelper->encode(t("Wrong security answer!"));
            die; 
        }
    }
```

The script sanitizes different attributes (name, email and the message) and sends an email to a specified address and the one from the HTML form.
**My question:** Is the form secure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Secure: Not yet, but it's a start. Your validation is too strict in some places, and may result in the wrong email address being used. In particular here:

```
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
//a bit later on:
$email = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d"), '', stripslashes($email));
```

If the value of `$email` is one of these examples of ***valid*** email addresses:

```
!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}|~@example.org
"()<>[]:,;@\\\"!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{}| ~.a"@example.org
"very.(),:;<>[]\".VERY.\"very@\\ \"very\".unusual"@strange.example.com
```

you're stripping the slashes, which'll yield:

```
!#$%&'*+-=?^_`{}|~@example.org
"()<>[]:,;@"!#$%&'*+-=?^_`{}| ~.a"@example.org
"very.(),:;<>[]".VERY."very@ "very".unusual"@strange.example.com
```

Effectively *changing* the actual email address, and this may in turn turn a valid, though outlandish email address into an invalid one.
BTW: source for these email addresses [is the email wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address)

When it comes to email addresses: use `filter_validate($emai, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` and rely on that function's ability to validate the string. Don't do any processing of your own, especially not *after* having sanitized and validated the email address.
Bottom line, if you want to validate an email address, while allowing users to pass an (accidental) `\r` char, use this:

```
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER+_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    echo $jsonHelper->encode($email.' is an invalid address'));
}
```

On the other hand, you're not sanitizing the message and name as well as maybe you should. It's not unlikely your script is vulnerable to *mail injection*. [A must-read on this subject can be found here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/428076/PHP-Mail-Injection-Protection-and-E-Mail-Validatio).

Since we're all in the business of programming, I hope you'll understand I'm not going to repeat myself here, but I've dealt with mail injection previously on this site: [read my answer to this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36330/critique-sanitized-user-email-php-script/36354#36354), which focusses on injection a bit more.

*Some other niggles:*

- Please, as ever, try to stick to the coding standards as described by PHP-FIG. Most, if not all, major players subscribe to this standard, so should you. [Check the standard here](http://www.php-fig.org).
  Things like `public function foobar(){` are not accepted, the opening brace should go on the next line. It may seem silly to stumble over this, but really: it isn't.
- don't use `die` in a method, and avoid using `echo`. I take it you're using a framework of sorts. Check if there's an ajax helper that outputs, or use the view to echo JSON content. And from within an action (controller method), don't call `die`, but rather `return`, signaling an uneventfull end of the controllers' job. `die` breaks the normal way of processing a request, which may cause problems down the road.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I still cannot understand why is my code vulnerable to mail injection? I make sure to remove all newlines.

Comment: I have followed the dream.in.code method of removing newlines. It is also reviewed on the link you provided as one of the viable options. Why is it vulnerable to mail injection?

Comment: @user3001234: Not quite: you're not removing the line-endings, but merely percent-encoding them. Looking at the PEAR `_sanitizeHeaders` method, I'd assume that alone does not suffice, since they remove `%0a`, too. I'm only guessing here, but I take it that, seeing as they remove this, there is a way to exploit encoded line-endings, too. You're also not checking for `<CR>` and the like. Perhaps consider calling `strip_tags` on the message, and send it with explicit _text_ headers

Comment: Should I be using the `_sanitizeHeaders` method from the page you provided? It appears to be secure.

Comment: @user3001234: You can use it for inspiration. Personally, I tend to avoid PEAR packages, because they do tend to raise notices, because of their tendency to try to be as backward-compatible as possible. Running PHP5.5, methods that don't specify their being `public`, `private` or `protected` and methods that are being called both as member functions and statics... that's just messy PHP4-style coding. The main point is: the sanitizing has all been written out, copy with pride (and in accordance with the licence)

Comment: Doing `$value = preg_replace('=((<CR>|<LF>|0x0A/%0A|0x0D/%0D|\\n|\\r)\S).*=i', null, $value);` for `$name`, `$email` and `$message` should be enough, I suppose. I don't want to use PEAR packages; I'm using Zend mail already.

Comment: @user3001234: _not_ for `$email`, for the email address `filter_validate($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL)` already removes any non-valid address chars. and I believe `"<CR>MyAddress"@example.org` is a valid email address, because the `<>` is contained within quotes. Just call the `preg_replace` on the name and message and you should be fine

Comment: Okay, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I used the dream.in.code method because I wasn't aware of `<CR>`. The table in the page you provided pretty much sums it up - the PEAR method is the safest one as far as I can see.

Comment: Also, any other remarks regarding security? Would you say that my contact form is secure now that I use the PEAR `preg_replace` method for removing newlines?

Comment: @user3001234: AFAIKT, yes, I'd say it's pretty secure. You don't seem to be storing the data in a DB anywhere (if you do, use prepared statements, and you're good). So the only things you need to check are: 1) validation and 2) mail injection. You've addressed both sufficiently, I do think

Comment: I use the ADO DB layer whenever I have to store/retrieve data from a database, so I suppose I'm fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've just noticed something strange - when using the PEAR method for sanitizing headers, the `preg_replace` removes all data that comes after the newline. Why is this and how do I solve it? The text message (email body) gets cut off.

Comment: I ended up using `$value = trim(str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d", "<CR>", "<LF>"), '', stripslashes($value)));` for `$message` and `$name`.