# Possible security issues in email validation

Tags: php, security, form, validation, email

I need feedback on this code regarding security issues.

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

//Validate first
if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email)) 
{
    echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
    exit;
}

if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}

$email_from = 'someemail@some.com';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "New Form submission";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n".
    "Here is the message:\n $message".

$to = "someemail@some.com";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thank-you.html');
```

I'm using this `IsInjected($str)` function to validate email addresses:

```
// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your first validation, I think you forgot to exit, you probably meant:

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
    exit;
}
```

To validate email addresses, you can use the `filter_var` method, like this:

```
function is_valid_email($str) {
    return filter_var($str, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}
```

For example:

```
function check_email($email) {
    printf("checking '%s': %s\n", $email, is_valid_email($email) ? 'OK' : 'INVALID');
}
check_email('joe@example.com');
check_email('bogus');
```

will output:

```
checking 'joe@example.com': OK
checking 'bogus': INVALID
```

For more details and (caveats!), [see the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php). Also [some more examples here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php).

Your original `IsInjected` method might still be useful for other purposes, that's why I created a new method for validating emails. If you keep it I would rename it to `hasInjectedChars` or `has_injected_chars`. And these lines can be improved:

> ```
>   if(preg_match($inject,$str))
>     {
>     return true;
>   }
>   else
>     {
>     return false;
>   }
> ```

you could write simply:

```
return preg_match($inject, $str);
```

Comment: should I get rid of this:  `// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}`  and replace it with this:  `function is_valid_email($str) {
    return filter_var($str, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}`

Comment: I inserted the     filter_var     method as you suggested and tested it. It seems I can write anything in the form email input box and it will submit it and goes through. I wonder why that happens?

Comment: I updated my post with more examples and explanation. I don't see how it's possible that `is_valid_email` would not work. I tested and works for me (see the example in my post). Btw `filter_var` was introduced in PHP 5.2.0, make sure your PHP is recent enough.

Comment: thanks again. Just want to make sure I am doing this right, pls advise: 1, I add this to the script:    function is_valid_email($str) {
    return filter_var($str, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}    right above the line:    function IsInjected($str)    2, I keep the    isInjected    method but rename it:    has_injected_chars    Is this what I have to do? if so, then I just test it by typing something into the form email box and submit it. If this works, what should happen after I submit, how do I know it worked exactly?

Comment: And change `if(IsInjected($visitor_email))` to: `if(!is_valid_email($visitor_email))`. Notice the `!` there, so that you will exit if the email is NOT valid. After this, invalid emails shouldn't work.

Comment: now it doesnt work even with a valid email address, nothing happens, no error msg just a blank page after I submit

Comment: I guess I should post the the full code again and the html form as well but I can not do that in the comment section here, this is my first time posting here so I am still not sure how it works

Comment: @JoeRay keep in mind that Code Review is about advising on working code, not troubleshooting. If your code doesn't work and you don't know why, Stack Overflow is the place, not here.

Comment: @janosn thanks again, the original code I posted works, I just wanted to get a review on the code security

Comment: If the original code works, I don't see how these changes could break it. The end result should be the same, but with less and cleaner code ;-) No?

Answer (score 1):

Just a short answer, because I've already posted a number of detailed reviews that deal with mail injection.

To validate an email address, all you really need to do is this:

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    throw new RuntimeException('invalid email address');
```

Optionally sanitizing that same email address first, to remove some, possibly harmful characters:

```
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```

That said, checking the email for dangerous characters is all very well, but don't forget about the rest of the user input. I'm not going to repeat myself here, just a couple of links to previous answers that deal with mail injection in detail:

- [PHP form with bot deterrent](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/41129/php-form-review/41318#41318)
- [Security of a "contact us" form](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40766/security-of-a-contact-us-form/40834#40834)
- [Critique sanitized user email PHP Script](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36330/critique-sanitized-user-email-php-script/36354#36354)

And a fairly detailed article on this topic [can be found here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/428076/PHP-Mail-Injection-Protection-and-E-Mail-Validatio). It discusses libs and tools that are already out there, free for you to use. It shows their features and, more importantly, the caveats.

On your code:

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit']))
    echo '';
```

This basically checks if the form was submitted, but if it wasn't your code still is executed as if the form *was* posted. Don't do that. Either redirect, throw an exception or `exit`.
`isset` is indeed the best way to check if a post parameter exists, which is why it's odd to see that you don't check the other paremeters:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

Should be:

```
$name = !isset($_POST['name']) ? null : $_POST['name'];
```

and so on. If you don't put that `isset` language construct (not a function, constructs are faster), then your code might emit notices:

```
$foo = array();
echo $foo['nonExistantIndex'];
```

Will issue a notice, because you're trying to access a non-existing index. to see the notices, set your ini file to the only correct development settings:

```
display_errors=1
error_reporting=E_STRICT | E_ALL
```

that way, any problem that exists in your code will be visible to you. This enables you to develop better code. Good practice should be the default/norm, not the goal.